# Changing Hourly averages to 30 minute averages in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I've been trying to change this and I'm failing... what am I getting wrong?!

I have this script which gives me hourly averages for the last 24 hours... how can I change it to 30 minute averages over 24 hours?

```
SELECT UID, 
        HOUR(collectionTime) AS hour, 
        ROUND(AVG(coldAisleTemp),1) AS coldAisleTemp, 
        ROUND(AVG(warmAisleTemp),1) AS warmAisleTemp, 
        ROUND(AVG(coldAisleHumidity),1) AS coldAisleHumidity, 
        ROUND(AVG(warmAisleHumidity),1) AS warmAisleHumidity
    FROM `temps` 
    WHERE 
        DATE_SUB(collectionTime, INTERVAL 1 HOUR) 
        AND collectionTime > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR) 
    GROUP BY 
        HOUR(collectionTime) 
    ORDER BY 
        UID ASC
```

I've tried several things, but I won't share my attempts because I'm not sure they're going to help the situation!!

Here's the data in the database...

```
collectionTime      | coldAisleTemp | warmAisleTemp | coldAisleHumidity | warmAisleHumidity
2021-07-27 09:55:49 | 22.4          | 27.7          | 44                | 27
2021-07-27 09:54:49 | 22.4          | 27.7          | 44                | 27
2021-07-27 09:53:49 | 22.4          | 27.7          | 44                | 27
2021-07-27 09:52:49 | 22.4          | 27.7          | 44                | 27
2021-07-27 09:51:49 | 22.4          | 27.7          | 44                | 27
2021-07-27 09:50:49 | 22.4          | 27.7          | 44                | 27
2021-07-27 09:49:49 | 22.4          | 27.7          | 44                | 27
2021-07-27 09:48:49 | 22.4          | 27.7          | 44                | 27
2021-07-27 09:47:49 | 22.4          | 27.7          | 44                | 27
2021-07-27 09:46:49 | 22.4          | 27.7          | 44                | 27
2021-07-27 09:45:49 | 22.4          | 27.7          | 44                | 27
2021-07-27 09:44:49 | 22.4          | 27.7          | 44                | 27
2021-07-27 09:43:49 | 22.4          | 27.7          | 44                | 27
2021-07-27 09:42:49 | 22.4          | 27.7          | 44                | 27
2021-07-27 09:41:49 | 22.4          | 27.7          | 44                | 27
2021-07-27 09:40:49 | 22.4          | 27.7          | 44                | 27
2021-07-27 09:39:49 | 22.4          | 27.7          | 44                | 27
2021-07-27 09:38:49 | 22.4          | 27.7          | 44                | 27
2021-07-27 09:37:49 | 22.4          | 27.7          | 44                | 27
2021-07-27 09:36:49 | 22.4          | 27.7          | 44                | 27
2021-07-27 09:35:49 | 22.4          | 27.7          | 44                | 27
2021-07-27 09:34:49 | 22.4          | 27.7          | 44                | 27
2021-07-27 09:33:49 | 22.4          | 27.7          | 44                | 27
2021-07-27 09:32:49 | 22.4          | 27.7          | 44                | 27
2021-07-27 09:31:49 | 22.4          | 27.7          | 44                | 27
2021-07-27 09:30:49 | 22.4          | 27.7          | 44                | 27
2021-07-27 09:29:49 | 22.4          | 27.7          | 43                | 27
2021-07-27 09:28:49 | 22.4          | 27.7          | 43                | 27
2021-07-27 09:27:49 | 21.8          | 27.7          | 43                | 27
2021-07-27 09:26:49 | 21.8          | 27.7          | 43                | 27
2021-07-27 09:25:49 | 21.8          | 27.7          | 43                | 27
```

Comment: What would help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Not how I can make this more reproducible... - I'll edit with a bit more.

Comment: What is the purpose of the condition `DATE_SUB(collectionTime, INTERVAL 1 HOUR)`? As it is now, it doesn't do anything except reject a record when the `collectionTime`'s hour part is 1.

Comment: I think that a hangover from me trying to work out how to change it - not sure how it got left in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition `DATE_SUB(collectionTime, INTERVAL 1 HOUR)` makes little sense, so I would remove it, or replace it with an actual *comparison* of that expression with another date/time, like `NOW()` -- it depends on what the purpose was of this "condition".

As to the question, you can use an extra expression to group by (and to select) which identifies which half-hour the record belongs to: either 0 or 30:

```
SELECT   HOUR(collectionTime) as hour,
         (MINUTE(collectionTime) >= 30) * 30 as halfhour, 
         ROUND(AVG(coldAisleTemp),1) AS coldAisleTemp
FROM     temps
GROUP BY HOUR(collectionTime),
         (MINUTE(collectionTime) >= 30) * 30
```

NB: I didn't reproduce all the average expressions, nor the `while` clause, as they are not relevant to the question.

Comment: You, sir, are wonderful... thank you!

It was the (MINUTE(collectionTime) >= 30) * 30 as halfhour, I was missing

Comment: Indeed, it was the only thing I added ,-)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you to @trincot

Here's the updated code for completion:

```
SELECT UID, 
        HOUR(collectionTime) AS hour, 
        (MINUTE(collectionTime) >= 30) * 30 as halfhour, 
        ROUND(AVG(coldAisleTemp),1) AS coldAisleTemp, 
        ROUND(AVG(warmAisleTemp),1) AS warmAisleTemp, 
        ROUND(AVG(coldAisleHumidity),1) AS coldAisleHumidity, 
        ROUND(AVG(warmAisleHumidity),1) AS warmAisleHumidity
    FROM `temps` 
    WHERE 
        collectionTime > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR) 
    GROUP BY 
        HOUR(collectionTime), 
        (MINUTE(collectionTime) >= 30) * 30
    ORDER BY 
        UID ASC
```